# How to validate textbox

Tags: javascript

i have problem with my program. what i want is to validate the textbox if it is equal to data that i get from my database. if it's equal then set focus if not the textbox should be null and and will not able to enter. this is my sample code.Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
function sequence(varid) {

    var a = varid.indexOf("/")
    var b = varid.slice(0, a);
    b = parseInt(b)
    c = (b + 1)
    var f = varid.slice(a);

    if (window.event.keyCode == 13 || window.event.keyCode == 10) {

        var lot_number = document.getElementsByName("lot_number")[b].value;
        var lot_number_scan = document.getElementsByName("lot_number_scan")[b].value;

        var counting = document.getElementsByName("lot_number_scan");

        counting = counting.length;

        var newid = c + f
        if (c == counting) {
            document.getElementById("issued_by").focus();
        } else {
            lot_number_scan = lot_number_scan.replace(/(LO)/g, "-LO");
            lot_number_scan = lot_number_scan.replace(/-/, "");

            var check = (new RegExp(lot_number_scan, "gi").test(lot_number));

            if (check == true) {
                document.getElementById(newid).focus();
            } else {
                document.getElementsByName("lot_number_scan")[b].value = '';
                document.getElementsByName("lot_number_scan").focus();
            }

            document.getElementById(newid).focus();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

sorry for late reply.. what happen when i run that codes is, still enter though the entered data is not equal or not the same with the other data sorry if I'm not good in explanation i will give sample hope this can help.

**Data from database**      **Texbox**
123456828                      123456828
152685689                      123456828

Save Button

**Data from database** is just a display data that i post after filtering the sequence of  data. 
**Textbox** I scan barcode to input data.

If the entered data in the textbox is matches to the display data it automatically enter the second textbox and ready to scan again Im ok with that, What i want to happen is when the entered data is not match is should not enter to the second textbox or save button also when it enter wrong data it should automatically erase the wrong entered data and ask for correct one. hope you can understand what i want to happen I'm new in coding and self study so your help is very much needed and thank you s much..

Comment: So what happens when you run that code? It would be helpful if you told us which part you're stuck on. (It would also be helpful if you made your code easier for us to read by indenting it properly and by not having so many blank lines - I hope you don't mind, but I've taken care of that for you by formatting your code via [JsPretty.com](http://jspretty.com.)

Comment: Removed tags that aren't being addressed in the question - the question is only dealing with javascript, not php/mysql/ajax, so removed those tags.

Comment: It's ok sir your comment will be by guideline in posting since im new in posting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jquery and in that case you can check it and set value in it with different jquery selectors.

For Example:

```
$('input[type=text][id="textfieldId"]').val('myValueToBeSet');
```

Hope this might help you.